# Find Primary Key From Persistent Class in Devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, xpo

I have Added Persistent Class in in my webapplication. It contains 20 classes..,

In my Default.aspx.cs, I want to get list of Primary key name from all classes in Persistent class.. How can i find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that you use XPO:

```
foreach (XPClassInfo classInfo in xpoSession.Dictionary.Classes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(classInfo.FullName + "=" + classInfo.KeyProperty);
}
```

If you have simple primary key, use `classInfo.KeyProperty.Name` to fetch its name.